# Missing PhysXLoader.dll Need For Speed Shift

Tags: laptop, dll, gaming

I run Need for speed Shift and get this error. What can I do. I installed directX from official MS site.

P.S. I have an Asus laptop with Intel Pentium Dual Core and Intel HD Graphics. Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file you need isn't part of the Microsoft DirectX package. It's part of nVidia's PhysX software suite available [here](http://www.nvidia.com/object/physx-9.12.0613-driver.html).

Comment: Thanx. Doesn't it matter that I haven't NVidia GPU?

Comment: Nvidia PhysX is a physics engine. It is usually relying on the GPU for its processing, but it can work (severely downgraded) in software mode, with hacks. By default, if the GPU doesn't support PhysX, it is disabled. However, since the games are built against Physics libraries, the engine libraries are needed even if the GPU doesn't support it (otherwise said: even if the libraries are just detecting the absence of PhysX support and disabling the engine), or you get a "missing dll" error.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the install disk for *Need for Speed: Shift 2*.

There should be a folder called "phys install". Run the installer, remove it, then reinstall. You might have to do the same for the game.

Comment: remove and reinstall what?